# SQL query calculate percent true from 10 boolean columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called "Grades" with 10 boolean columns called PassA, PassB, PassC, PassD, etc.
I am trying to make a query that will give me the percent of "true" in each column?

```
ID   PassA  PassB   PassC
1      x      x       
2             x       x
3      x
4             x
```

Expected query result (or equivalent):

```
PassA  PassB   PassC
50%    75%     25%
```

It is an Access SQL statement.

I seem to be able to do it with one column (see below) but wan't to do it will all the columns in 1 query. All ideas are very welcome? Thank you!

```
SELECT PassA, (count(PassA(*)*100 / (Select count(*)FROM Grades} AS Total
FROM Grades
Group by PassA;
```

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not _fields_. And I'd consider to have 10 rows with one boolean instead of 1 row with 10 booleans.

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using. Also add the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table and sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements. Show the expected result with that sample data.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback -my apologies for the poor wording. I have now edited the question to hopefully be more concise.

Comment: Even Gustavs answer works, your data-model is poor as jarlh has noticed! Read about database normalization!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is Access SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    Avg(Abs([PassA])) AS AvgA, 
    Avg(Abs([PassB])) AS AvgB, 
    Avg(Abs([PassC])) AS AvgC
FROM 
    Grades;
```

Then set the *Format* property of the fields to **Percent** and *count of decimals* to **0**:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you very much! You have saved me a lot of headache:-)

Answer (score 1):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  ROUND(100.0 * AVG(IIF(PassA, 1, 0)), 2) & '%' AS PercentA,
  ROUND(100.0 * AVG(IIF(PassB, 1, 0)), 2) & '%' AS PercentB,
  ROUND(100.0 * AVG(IIF(PassC, 1, 0)), 2) & '%' AS PercentC
FROM Grades
```

For MS Access this will work too:

```
SELECT
  ROUND(100.0 * AVG(-PassA), 2) & '%' AS PercentA,
  ROUND(100.0 * AVG(-PassB), 2) & '%' AS PercentB,
  ROUND(100.0 * AVG(-PassC), 2) & '%' AS PercentC
FROM Grades
```

because `TRUE` is stored as `-1` and `FALSE` as `0`.
Results:

```
PercentA    PercentB    PercentC
50%         75%         25%
```

Answer (score -1):

For Oracle, I would do the following:

```
WITH TOT_COUNT AS (SELECT 1 "ID", COUNT(*) "Total" FROM Grades)
SELECT "ID",
       COUNT(DECODE(GMLDA, '8', 'X', Null))/"Total" "ScoreA",
       COUNT(DECODE(GMR001, 'D15', 'X', Null))/"Total" "ScoreB",
       COUNT(DECODE(GMR002, 'B', 'X', Null))/"Total" "ScoreC"
FROM (SELECT 1 "ID", T1.* FROM Grades T1) JOIN TOT_COUNT USING("ID")
GROUP BY "ID", "Total";
```

It's basically nullifying the "False" values so they don't get counted. Of course, you can do it the other way around.

Advantage: No DDL permissions needed.